# input 3 digit number and print each digit in descending order

Tags: java, loops

I already have the result but its in ascending order. When i change the `i++` to  `i--` is print `Your program failed to compile possibly due to an infinity loop.`

```
Scanner in = new  Scanner(System.in);
int a = in.nextInt();
int i,j,p,r;

for(i = 0; i < a; i++){
    p = a;
    while(p != 0){
        r = p % 10;
        if(r == i){
            System.out.println(r);
        }
    p = p / 10;
    };
}
```

*input:214 Expected output:412*

Comment: Why is expected output 412?

Comment: What was the input?

Comment: @NomadMaker _input:214_

Comment: Digits of the number in “ascending order” would be 1, 2, 4. Please clarify your title/question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be making this a lot more complicated than it needs to be.

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = in.nextInt();
int p = a;
int r;
while (p > 0) {
    r = p % 10;
    System.out.print(r);
    p /= 10;
}
```

If the input is 214, then the above code will print 412.

Answer (score 1):

```java
import java.util.*; 

class Test 
{ 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.print("Enter a number with three or more digits: "); 
        int n = sc.nextInt(); 
        int[] digits = Integer.toString(num).chars().map(c -> c-'0').toArray(); 
        Arrays.sort(digits); 
        for(int d : digits) System.out.print(d); 
    } 
}
```

Input will be - 125863

Output will be - 123568

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method and also you can change the sort type beeing descending or ascending:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int number = in.nextInt();
String sNumber = String.valueOf(number);
Integer[] digits = new Integer[sNumber.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < sNumber.length(); i++) {
    digits[i] = Character.getNumericValue(sNumber.charAt(i));
}

Arrays.sort(digits, Collections.reverseOrder()); // will sort descending
for (Integer integer : digits) {
    System.out.print(integer);
}
```